# Trying to draw a simple line loop

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm going crazy. All I want to do is draw a simple line loop. But all I get is a diagonal line from the origin out to (-0.5, 0.0, -0.5). What am I doing wrong?

```
@interface Frustum : NSObject {
    GLuint _vertexArray;
    GLuint _vertexBuffer;
    GLfloat left_side[4][3];
}

- (id) init;
- (GLuint) getVertexArray;
- (void) render;

@end


@implementation Frustum

- (id) init {
        left_side[0][0] = -0.5f;  left_side[0][1] = 0.0f;  left_side[0][2] = -0.5f;
        left_side[1][0] = 0.5f;  left_side[1][1] = 0.0f;  left_side[1][2] = -0.5f;
        left_side[2][0] = 0.5f;  left_side[2][1] = 0.0f;  left_side[2][2] = -0.5f;
        left_side[3][0] = -0.5f;  left_side[3][1] = 0.0f;  left_side[3][2] = -0.5f;        

        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

        glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);

        // SOMETHING IS WRONG IN HERE, BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT!!!!!
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*12, left_side, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(left_side), NULL);

        glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

    }

    return self;
}

- (void) render {
    glLineWidth(2.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your y or z values, so you form an actual loop.

```
(-.5, 0, 0 )
(.5, 0, 0 )
(.5, .5, 0)
(-.5 .5, 0 )
```

will form a line loop.  You just have the same y, so that's a line.

Remember, the default camera will looking down the -z axis, so it won't see changes in z (unless you've rotated the camera).

Comment: I can't believe that I spent this much time and didn't see that I was just drawing the same line twice. Thanks for pointing that out. BTW, I didn't mention, but my camera was rotated to be looking down the x axis. Thank you!

Comment: Can't click that for 10 minutes.